# How to handle JSON encoded strings using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, json

I am currently using Django to construct JSON encoded objects which a retrieved using jQuery.getJSON().  The standard simplejson encoder encodes strings according to the JSON ["standard"](http://www.json.org), i.e. any string containing a '/' is translated to '/'.  Therefore if one of my parameters is a url, e.g. http://example.com/image.jpg it is passed to the client as http://example.com/image.jpg.  JQuery does not decode these strings (it does a straight eval), therefore it I try to use the url as the src attribute for an image it does not work.  What is the best way to handle strings (e.g. urls) in JavaScript that have been "JSON-escaped"?

**Update:** There was a bug elsewhere in the code, jQuery.getJSON() does the correct unescaping.

Comment: Are you sure jQuery isn't un-escaping your strings, or are you guessing?

Comment: I've tested it and inspected the code.  It uses eval(string).

Comment: Sorry, you're right, eval(string) does work.

Comment: 2 more reputation points and you'll be able to close your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [JSON.parse](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) will do it.